# How to enable Basic Authentication for a particular controller action in RestFUL API Service

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, basic-authentication, restful-authentication

I have RestFUL service deployed in a server with "Windows Authentication" enabled in IIS.

Now I want to enable "Basic Authentication", I expect the credential window to pop up when a particular controller action is triggered. I referred the post [Basic Authentication](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/basic-authentication). Unfortunately, couldn't make it work yet.

This rest service I am consuming in a website, this website holds "Windows Authentication", when this website access the particular controller action, I am getting UnAuthorized error. This error is triggered before going to controller itself, it returns that message. I found this by using log.

Please suggest me with a best solution. Thanks in advance.